# How to import .stl mesh and visualize?

Tags: mesh, stl

I am really new in 3d Rendering and like.

I've generated .stl mesh files using Fiji/ImageJ.
I imported them in 3dSlicer and I can see them.

When I'd tried in Blender (hoping to have nicer rendering options), they are imported but I cannot see them anywhere.

[Here is an example of the .stl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QDVvfhKakGFA4gRaF9bu_3nRA3eS3tR0/view?usp=sharing)

Here a rendering of the .stl with 3dSlicer:
[image: .stl 3dSlicer rendering]

This is what I (don't) see in Blender
[image: stl render blender]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi :). The mesh could be too big/small to be visible. Go to *View > Frame selected* to zoom in on your object.

Comment: Also, After importing you need to center you origin so that scaling is done properly.
"Origin to Center of Mass"
And then set location to 0,0,0